# Amplify with react - relationship - not able to associate a related item in create form

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am very new to the amplify/react world and stuck on below.

How do I attach an existing item in the create form?

I have two data models with a 1:1 relationship. In the autogenerated create form I do not see an option to attached an existing pickupaddresses. In Amplify studio when I navigate to Content management, somehow amplify adds that functionality ("Add Item") in the content creation form. I want to replicate what content creation form looks like

```
type ShippingLabel @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  ordernumber: String!
  addressline1: String
  addressline2: String
  city: String
  postalcode: String
  country: String
  status: deliverystatus
  customerName: String
  customerPhone: AWSPhone
  customerEmail: AWSEmail
  customerNotes: String
  PickupAddresses: PickupAddresses @hasOne
}


type PickupAddresses @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  addressline1: String
  addressline2: String
  city: String
  postalcode: String
  country: String
}
```

**Auto-generated form** (No option to associate pickup address)
[Auto generated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkOIh.png)

**Content Management form in amplify studio** (has an option to search and add a pick up address)

[Create content form - desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6cw7.png)

Couldn't find a document or post in updating the autogenerated forms

Answer (score 0):

Following the example provided by the [AWS Amplify documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-one-relationship), your code is correct.

**Example Code:**

```
type Project @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  team: Team @hasOne
}

type Team @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

To create the mutation on the front-end, the example they have provided is this:

```
mutation CreateProject {
  createProject(input: {projectTeamId: "team-id", name: "Some Name"}) {
    team {
      name
      id
    }
    name
    id
  }
}
```

You can now follow the [mutations](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/mutate-data/q/platform/js/#mutations) documentation to ensure you create the request accurately, to meet the desired use-case.